# How can I use a variable with a value which is declared inside a function, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

```
function pswrd_gnrtr(length){

    var values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@#$";
    var result = "";
    for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
        result += values.charAt(Math.floor((Math.random() * values.length)+1)+1);    
    }
    alert(result);
}
```

I want to use the "result" outside the function??

I tried to declare the result outside the function but it didn't work it remains null.

Comment: You can `return result;` back to the caller. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: You could also do `window.result = ""; ` then you can access window.result from anywhere on the page. This is typically not great though, as you pollute the global namespace.

Comment: I think returning the result would be best, but you don't have to pollute the global namespace, just declare the variable without a value outside the function and set inside the function. If your function is inside other program blocks at least you don't get global pollution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the result:

```
function passwordGenerator(length) {
  let values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@#$";
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += values.charAt(Math.floor((Math.random() * values.length) + 1) + 1);
  }
  return result;
}

let password = passwordGenerator(6);
console.log(password);
let longPassword = passwordGenerator(20);
console.log(longPassword);
```

Some good practices:

- Use readable names for functions and variables, **passwordGenerator** is easier to understand than **pswrd_gnrtr**
- Use camelCasing not snake_casing in JavaScript (in other languages this might be different, for example Python has a preference for snake_casing).
- Always use **let** instead of **var** when you declare your variables, since **let** sets the variable scope to be the program block, similar to most other languages, while **var** sets it to the function scope (unusual when compared to other languages) and also has some strange behaviors built in, like 'hoisting'.
- In short: Make your code readable to yourself and others with as little risk for confusion over how things work as possible.